# Remove files in client-side and rewirte _onChage()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, client-side

I'm having two issues with client-side:

1. When files changed, how to remove old files that in the file list,
   and just upload the new files?
2. If I have a "remove all" button, how can I remove all files in client-side?

I'm using a basic plugin. (jquery.fileupload.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en, i used my own way to solve this, i havenot kown wheather it is good.
i hope for better ideas.

1. add pfiles options to blueimp.fileupload, like in jquery.fileupload.js:

   $.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {

   ```
   options: {
       // The drop target element(s), by the default the complete document.
       // Set to null to disable drag & drop support:
       dropZone: $(document),
       pfiles:null, // this is for marking the selected files
       // The paste target element(s), by the default the complete document.
       // Set to null to disable paste support:
       pasteZone: $(document)
     ...
   ```

   }}
2. in _onAdd function add like :

   _onAdd: function (e, data) {...

   ```
        that.pfiles=new Array(); // files array
       $.each(fileSet || data.files, function (index, element) {
          ...
           };
           that.pfiles.push(newData); // add to array
           return (result = that._trigger('add', e, newData));
       });
       return result;
   }
   ```
3. when use it like:

   $(function($) {'use strict';

   ```
     $.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {
          _onChange : function(e) {
               this._cancelHandler();
               this._super(e);
          },
          _initEventHandlers : function() {
               this._super();
               this._on($('#cancel-button'), {
                    click : this.cancel
               });
          },
          cancel : function(e) {
               $('#file-upload-info-list').hide();
               $('#upload-file-preview').html('');
               this._cancelHandler();
          },
          // here the pfiles is used...
          _cancelHandler : function(e) {
               if(this.pfiles != null) {
                    $.each(this.pfiles, function(index, element) {
                         element.submit = null;
                    });
                    this.pfiles = null;
               }
          }
     });
   ```

   });

this is my way.